# how to remove duplicate button

Tags: ios

This is my button creation function.

```
  -(void)buttonCreate {
  //oneBtn5 Button
  oneBtn5 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  oneBtn5.frame = CGRectMake(316, 389, 51, 21);
  oneBtn5.tag = 5;
  [oneBtn5 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [oneBtn5 addTarget:self action:@selector(oneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
  [oneBtn5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1c.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [self.view addSubview:oneBtn5];
}
```

I will show button using viewonload(),

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self buttonCreate];
 }
```

This is my restart function, if i clicked the restart, new button will create.

```
- (void)RestartAction {
    [self buttonCreate];
  }
```

My problem is how to remove duplicate button when i click the restart.  It's there any way to solve this problem.

Comment: You can check based on your tag. So before you run the block of code inside buttonCreate, check if (oneBtn5.tag != 5)

Comment: Can't understand why you have to remove it instead of updating it's state/title etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)buttonCreate {
  //oneBtn5 Button
  if (oneBtn5 != null)
      [oneBtn5 removeFromSuperview];

  oneBtn5 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  oneBtn5.frame = CGRectMake(316, 389, 51, 21);
  oneBtn5.tag = 5;
  [oneBtn5 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [oneBtn5 addTarget:self action:@selector(oneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
  [oneBtn5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1c.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [self.view addSubview:oneBtn5];
}
```

Comment: I had an image array.  I want to get that image from array one by one to display it on imageView. i.e., get the first image to display it and i have some function and process using that image When the function over then i want second image, third,....

Comment: This is a new question accept this one and post a new question. post link here I will answer.

Comment: i click "Ask Question" link i got this error  Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more. So please answer me in this page itself

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the button from it's superview:

```
-(void)buttonCreate {
    if (oneBtn5.superView) {
        [oneBtn5 removeFromSuperview];
    }
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do this in buttonCreate

```
if(oneBtn5==nil)
{
     oneBtn5 = [UIButton buttonWith....];
     [self.view addsubview: oneBtn5;
}
```

button only inits and adds once

Answer (score 0):

Use this as :

```
-(void)buttonCreate {
    if ([self.view.subviews containsObject:oneBtn5]) {
            [oneBtn5 removeFromSuperview];
        }
   // YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a property, as people tell you, check if it exists previously.

```
if(!self.oneBtn5){
     //instance of button
     self.oneBtn5 = [UIButton buttonWith....];
     [self.view addsubview: self.oneBtn5];

}else{
     //change stuff you need like text or frame

}
```

The problem is that you are creating new instances of the button instead of reusing the previous one.

Comment: how to reuse that button instead of creating new button.  Because i have animation after the button is created. i.e., i want to move that button one place to another then button will hide.  could you suggest me how to stop that animation and reusing that button

Comment: Depends on the way you move the button. If you are using transformations it is really easy, if you are changing the frame it could have problems with the performance and the results.

Comment: I am using this one CGRect frame = oneBtn.frame;
 CGRect frame1 = reffButton.frame; frame.origin.x = frame1.origin.x; 
    frame.origin.y = frame1.origin.y; 
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 3.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
        [oneBtn setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.4, .4)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        oneBtn.hidden = YES;
        price = [resultText.text intValue];}];
    oneBtn.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)buttonCreate {
  //oneBtn5 Button
  if (oneBtn5 ){
      [oneBtn5 removeFromSuperview];
       oneBtn5=nil;   // release the memory
      }

  oneBtn5 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  oneBtn5.frame = CGRectMake(316, 389, 51, 21);
  oneBtn5.tag = 5;
  [oneBtn5 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [oneBtn5 addTarget:self action:@selector(oneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
  [oneBtn5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1c.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [self.view addSubview:oneBtn5];
}
```

You must write `oneBtn = nil` after `[oneBtn5 removeFromSuperview]`  to release the memory for the previously created button. As `[oneBtn5 removeFromSuperview];` remove the button from its superview but does not release memory.You must release the memory by setting it to `nil`.